# \ref{} only prints the counter without fancy stuff

Tags: ref

Here's a MWE that shows what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,blindtext, enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{
  label={$\square$ {\small\oldstylenums{\arabic*}}},
  leftmargin=2em,
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{first} An item
    \item \label{second} A second item
\end{enumerate}
See point \ref{first}, but avoid looking at \ref{second}!
\end{document}
```

In the output, What I see is

> See point ▢ 1, but avoid looking at ▢ 2!

Of course I would like to remove the "▢" symbol. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use `ref={\arabic*}`  You do know there is a manual?

Comment: You mean as an option of `enumitem`? That's fine; I didn't know how to search for it.

Comment: You can view & refer this at **enumitem** documentation, you may use this command in DOS prompt `>texdoc enumitem` ...

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the fact that each package comes with a documentation. What I didn't know was that enumitem provides a feature that solves my problem

Comment: @JohnKormylo Please, write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can also specify `ref` separately from `label` with `\setlist`.  See page 3 of the enumitem manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,blindtext, enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{
  label={$\square$ {\small\oldstylenums{\arabic*}}},
  leftmargin=2em,
  ref={\arabic*}
}
\
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{first} An item
    \item \label{second} A second item
\end{enumerate}
See point \ref{first}, but avoid looking at \ref{second}!
\end{document}
```